# How to call a user defined method in angular material table?

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

How to call a user defined method in angular material table? I am using a class object instead of an Interface and when I call that method and its not working. I was able to display the properties but not the method output.

Here is the code snippet.

```
export class User implements IUser {

constructor(public id:number, public email: string,
  public first_name: string, public last_name: string, public avatar: string) {
    console.error("Construcor Eroor.")
  }

  upper(): string {
    console.log(this.email.toUpperCase())
    return this.email.toUpperCase();
  }
}



<ng-container matColumnDef="upper">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        upper
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user ">
        {{user.upper}} <!-- calling a method in the User class -->
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Here is the complete stackblitz link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-reactive-table-ddcsq4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map your response from your service (`sampleSvc`) into an array of `User` objects, such that you will be able to access the User instance, thus able to call the `upper()` method from the `User` class.

```
this.sampleSvc.findByKey(key).subscribe(data => {
  const users = data.map(obj => new User(
    obj.id,
    obj.email,
    obj.first_name,
    obj.last_name,
    obj.avatar,
  ));
  this.userSubject.next(users);
});
```

In addition, on your template component.html, you will need to call the `upper()` method

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="upper">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    upper
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user ">
    {{user.upper()}}
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

I have fixed it in your demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-reactive-table-n134w3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsample%2Fuser.datasource.ts).

Comment: This works wentjun, thanks. Is there any way to convert this to class object instead of manually doing it?

Comment: @GopikrishnaMandapati Hmm.. Unfortunately, I think this is the fastest way to convert it into a class object. I am sure there are other ways, but it will involve iterating through the array and converting it into the `User` object

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code:

app.component.html:

```
<hello [name]='name'></hello>
<app-sample></app-sample>
```

With the above edited code, you will be able to see the `name` as Angular:
[image]

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I would like to call the method inside my material table template. Not sure how the above code will help me on this aspect.

Comment: when I write my answer, at that time your post was incomplete, after I posted the above answer, you updated your stack post. Based upon your previous post, in the stack blitz, the name ```Angular``` was not showing up, So I assumed you are referring to that.

Comment: update your stackblitz, with the provided code. I will try to post an answer to your question.